# Create parent/child relation in SQL server based on the below scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

[image]

In this picture, **2018_9UKDT - UKD Expense Total** is parent of           **2018_9Q400 - UKD Indirects** and this in turn is parent to                **98064 - IT SDS Costs, 98063 - ACS in charges, 98012 - UKD - Central.**

Could someone let me know how to create parent child relation using T-SQL which has upto 10 levels.

**Table creation**

```
create table Test
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    NAME VARCHAR (255),
    Level Varchar(25)
);

insert into test (name) values
('     2018_9UKDT - UKD Expense Total'),
('          2018_9Q400 - UKD Indirects'),
('               98064 - IT SDS Costs'),
('               98063 - ACS in charges'),
('               98012 - UKD - Central'),
('          2018_9Q300 - UKD Non Opex Total');
```

and the output would be in the below attached screen shot.
Basically from least level to increasing order.

[image]

Comment: In your example - "9KR02 - Risk and Control..." is the child of what CCName, and how do you know that?

Comment: Hey @ZoharPeled, It is know by the space before the texts.

Comment: @Babulal should use underId/Parenid column

Comment: Hey @Ravi, each child will have a row of data containing their respective parent hierarchy like Child, parent_level_1,parent_level_2,parent_level_3,parent_level_4 till parent_level_10

Comment: use `hierarchyid` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @Babulal in which table

Comment: Yes, you know it's on the 4th level, but which of the 3rd level items is it's parent?

Comment: I mean, it's easy to get the levels: `SELECT  name, DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(name) - LEN(LTRIM(name))) As Level FROM Test` - but that leaves us with three 3rd level items, each has the potential to be the 4th level item's parent.

Comment: Hey @ZoharPeled, Apologies for this. i have went through the data and rectified it in the above screen shot. basically it will follow a tree structure with valid spaces between parent and child

Comment: Can we assume the order of the identity column is the correct order of the data?  (without a column to order by, the order of the records is arbitrary, because database tables are unsorted by nature).

Comment: Yes @ZoharPeled, Order is correct based on the parent/child relation. So whenever there is descent, the above one is its parent.

Comment: Ok, now the sample data is clear. What about the desired results? please [edit] the question again to include it as well.

Comment: Hey @ZoharPeled Added the output screen shot. Basically first column will be the least level/child and then next columns will be the parent in increasing order. for example from our sample data, least level will be 98031 - UKD Cost Challenge (RM) then its immediate parent (Parent lvl 1) should be 2018_9QB4F - UKD Marketing General Function and then its immediate parent (Parent lvl 2) would be 2018_9QB41 - Marketing and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know you have a max level of 10, you can use a couple of common table expressions and conditional aggregation:

```
With CTE1 AS 
(
SELECT  Id, 
        name, 
        DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY LEN(name) - LEN(LTRIM(name)) DESC) As Level
FROM Test
), CTE2 AS
(
SELECT  Id, 
        Name, 
        Level,
        ISNULL((SELECT MIN(ID)
         FROM CTE1 As t1
         WHERE T1.Level > T0.Level 
         ), Id) As ParentId
FROM CTE1 As T0
)

SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 1 THEN Trimmed END) As Level1
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 2 THEN Trimmed END) As Level2
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 3 THEN Trimmed END) As Level3
      ,MAX(CASE WHEN Level = 4 THEN Trimmed END) As Level4
      -- more of the same
FROM CTE2
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(Name)) As Trimmed) As DRY
GROUP BY ParentId
```

Results (for the sample data posted on the question):

```
    Level1                      Level2                          Level3                              Level4
    98064 - IT SDS Costs        2018_9Q400 - UKD Indirects      2018_9UKDT - UKD Expense Total      NULL
```

Please note that for multiple root nodes, it will be difficult to know where the root node is (basically, you could have `Level1`, `Level2` ... as null, where at least one other node have more children.

Therefor, you should probably have the root node on the left most column. To do that, change the `dense_rank` order by from `DESC` to `ASK`, and the condition on the subquery in the second cte from `WHERE T1.Level > T0.Level` to `WHERE T1.Level < T0.Level`.

Comment: Hey @Zohar Peled, This solution worked by adding a small condition to your solution as per below                                                                                                           
        SELECT  T0.Id, 
        T0.CCNAME, 
        T0.Level,  
        (SELECT MAX(ID)
         FROM CTE1 As T1
         WHERE T1.Level = T0.Level - 1 AND T0.ID > T1.ID
     ) As ParentId
FROM CTE1 As T0